# Return a variable from python script for use in ipython console

Tags: python

Is there a way to return a variable from a python script (.py) so that it can be used in the ipython console?  I have a python script that I run from the ipython console in Spyder.  A pandas dataframe is created in the script.  I would like that dataframe to be passed out of the script.  I know I could do this if I turned the whole script into a function and use `return(mydataframe)`, but is there a way to do this with a script instead of a function?

Comment: You could, for example, save the dataframe to a file, and have the other script read it back from the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a python script that I run from the ipython console in Spyder.

If by command line interface, you mean the REPL (what you get when you just type `python` in your shell), you can use the `ipython` interface, and then use the [magic command `%load`](http://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/magics.html#magic-load) to import and run the file that creates the dataframe. Once the cell is run, the dataframe will be available to you.

So the steps would be:

1. Save the contents of the cell(s) that create the dataframe as a normal `.py` file.
2. Launch a new instance of `ipython`
3. Type `%load the_name_of_the_file.py`
4. Execute the cell

Now, the dataframe is available to you.